# How could we know if the a view has been layout?

Tags: android, android-view

I'm getting a view top coordinate using the following

```
view.getTop();
```

This will return 0 initially, and after it has been layout, it will get the right coordinate based on the marginTop() set.

My question, from the view, how could we know if the view has been layout accordingly (e.g. the getTop return the right value)?

My usage scenario is as below. I'm trying to get the view coordinate during onScroll, but this will be called the very first time the view is initialize, and hence `getTop()` returns 0, which is not the right value for the first time. I want to avoid considering that scenario... but only start the onScroll listener when it does has the proper value.

```
    myList.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            int top = view.getTop();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = view.getViewTreeObserver();
viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout () {
        int top = view.getTop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, used that. Looks like most of the function of handling need to be inserted into the onGlobalLayout initialization. Thanks!